# How to smooth lines in MapServer 5.6.8?

Tags: mapserver, style, line, xml, smoothing

I have a map of property lines in MapServer and the lines look rough and have jagged edges and I wonder if there is anyway to make the lines appear smoother and more rounded in Mapserver 5.6.8?

The layer settings look like the following in XML:

```
<layer datasource="ds_PROPERTY" name="ds_PROPERTY" type="line">[datasource:ds_PROPERTY.mapfile-datasource]
    <class>
        <name>Properties</name>
        <style>
             <color>0 0 0</color>
            <size>3</size>
            <width>2</width>
            <outlinecolor>0 0 0 </outlinecolor>
            <antialias>TRUE</antialias>
        </style>            
    </class>        
    <opacity>100</opacity>
</layer>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible with version 5.6.8 but if you update to version 6.4 you can use the SIA shape smoothing algorithm. The RFC of the feature is in http://mapserver.org/development/rfc/ms-rfc-94.html and current documentation about the usage in http://mapserver.org/output/shape_smoothing.html#shape-smoothing.

If you must to stay with the old 5.6.8 the only thing you can do is to pre-process the data with some other tools to shorter and more smooth segments. Applying a style that draws thicker lines makes some smoothing effect as well.